# Does Zbar or libdecodeqr work in 64bit Windows？

Tags: zbar

I need to use QR Code decoder in my porject(C++),but I found these library  didn't work .

I follow this  zbar example http://blog.ayoungprogrammer.com/2013/07/tutorial-scanning-barcodes-qr-codes.html

when I select win32 solution platform

**build: successful run:app error 0xc000007b**

**when I select x64   solution platform**

many error  “lnk2019 unresolved external symbol ... ”appear

**dev-environment：Windows 8.1 x64 , OpenCV 2.4.6   VS2012-Ultimate**

so,I'm suppose that this library were built for 32bit device

Does Zbar or libdecodeqr work in 64bit Windows？

Answer (score 0):

realizing the question has gone unanswered for two years....

I am using zbar for windows version 0.10 command line utility (which was last modified in 2009) on my Windows 10 x64 and previously on Win 8.1 x64 with no problems.

I can't comment on the libraries, but presumably they were used to build the command line tools which work fine.